# Get all characters before a whitespace in LUA (ROBLOX)

Tags: lua, roblox

I have a 5x5 grid of tiles that are number like:

Numerical order Row number(eg: 1 1 would be the first tile on the first row and 6 2 would be the first tile on the second row)

I need to get the blocks around a clicked tile (above, below, left and right), I thought about doing this by taking off numbers from the numerical order and row number. I wrote this:

```
        local ab = tostring(tonumber(v.Name)-5)..tostring(tonumber(string.sub(v.Name,-1))-1)
        local be = tostring(tonumber(v.Name)+5)..tostring(tonumber(string.sub(v.Name,-1))+1)
```

ab being the tile above and be being the tile below. I ran into a problem where I cannot get the first two letters of a tile who's numerical order is two digits using one line (I don't want to use if statements since I'm pretty sure there's a one line solution)

I came up with a solution and that is to get all the characters before the whitespace (which separates the order from the row number) but I have no idea how to write it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just ask for all non-whitespace characters from the beginning of the string:

```
print(("test123 more456"):match("^(%S+)"))
```

This should print `test123`.